# I want to extract table form website using excel vba by entering certain date and submitting data . I want Table of that date

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

'I have tried this, this dose not contain the code for extracting table.
I need to do these 4 things using vba macro.

```
1.enter the website 
2.enter the date 
3.Search the price form the website 
4.Return the table to the excel worksheet form the website 

Sub ClickButton()
Dim ie As Object
Dim form As Variant, button As Variant
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement


Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
dateinput = InputBox("Enter date of for searching table eg. 2015-01-19")
With ie
.Visible = True
.navigate ("http://www.sharesansar.com/today.php#")

While ie.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend
ie.document.getElementsbyname("date").Item.innertext = dateinput

Set form = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("form")
Set Buttoon = form(0).onsubmit
form(0).submit

End With
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

`Set Button = form(0).onsubmit`

ought to be a button.